# WooCommerce woocommerce_new_order_item hook

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the `woocommerce_new_order_item` hook in my functions.php file.

The code I have is:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order_item', 'wc_order_item_added',  1, 1  );
function wc_order_item_added($item_id, $item, $order_id) {
    global $mysqli;

    //$order = new WC_Order( $item_id );

    $sql = $mysqli->query("INSERT into a_test (one) values ('".$item_id."');");
}
```

Which I found from: http://hookr.io/actions/woocommerce_new_order_item/

But the `$order_id` variable is not being returned. The only variable that is working is, `$item_id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the action to this

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order_item', 'wc_order_item_added',  1, 3 );
```

The last parameter is number of variables that the callback accepts

Comment: ah i see - do you know how to read `$item` ? I tried both `$item->name` and `$item["name"]` but neither are working and `$item` on its own just returns `Array`

Comment: Do die(var_dump($item)) ; to see what's in the object